# Creating a class in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, class

I have read the docs and everything but I'm very confused. I never needed to create a class before and now I do.

I want to have something like:

```
TextDocument.Save("filepath", "contents of file to save");
```

and stuff like:

```
Application.Create("filepath", "text/code to save");
```

and:

```
Stylesheet.Save("filepath", "contents");
```

and have these in a class and create methods for them but I'm very confused as to how to go about doing it can somebody please help me with this?

thank you,
jase

Comment: Are you looking for smt like: **Right Click** the project --> **Add** --> **New Item** --> **Class** ?

Comment: "i never needed to create a class before" -> It's a joke, or ;-) ?

Comment: @jdehaan - sure, it is page 1 stuff - but I'm willing to give the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: nah it wasn't a joke but i do see the humor in it. i know i have read about classes before but i never practiced or anything because i just haven't had the need to use them... makes it a whole lot harder when you have adhd. although thats not my excuse

Comment: No problem, I was just surprised to see valid C# snippets and wondering how one could write a single line of C# without having met a class. There are only stupid answers (and comments like mine haha) and never stupid questions. I wish you luck with your project!

Comment: @jdehaan: you'd be surprised how many programmers don't know what a class is and are afraid to create one (even though it is a very mundane task yet integral to our work).

Comment: btw, this is a very classy question

Comment: @Itay - thanks for the edit. iwas just thinking about correcting the code formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yay! I created my first Class! :D hehehehe...

Here's the complete code. I don't know if it's the "best" way, or the most "efficient" way of doing this. But it works. I hope it can help others too:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public String FilePath,
            FileContents = null;

        public class TextDocument
        {
            public void Save(string FilePath, String FileContents)
            {
                File.WriteAllText(FilePath, FileContents);
            }
        }

        private void toolStripButton337_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FilePath = "this.txt";
            FileContents = "testing";

            TextDocument Document = new TextDocument();
            Document.Save(FilePath, FileContents);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you Russell Steen and Marc Gravell for your help! :D

Comment: You don't need to nest the TextDocument class inside the Form1 class. It can be also be declared outside the scope of Form1 or in another file.

Comment: hmm wow thanks for that spoike! when you say "in another file", would i just reference that file in Form1 like this: using MyClassFile; where the other usings are?

Comment: Almost, you won't need to do if they are in the same namespace (from the code it is "namespace MyApp"). The "using" statement is used when a class is declared in another namespace.

Answer (score 10):

Impossible to say without more code, but those *look* like static methods, i.e. create a new class (cs) file, and add something like:

```
using System.IO;
public class TextDocument {
   public static void Save(string path, string contents) {
       File.WriteAllText(path, contents);
   }
}
```

If `TextDocument` is actually an instance, take away the word `static`.

Note that to be callable, you also need to know about namespaces. The above is in the default namespace, but that is a bit vulgar. It should really be more like:

```
using System.IO;
namespace FooCorp.MagicApp {
    public class TextDocument {
        public static void Save(string path, string contents) {
            File.WriteAllText(path, contents);
        }
    }
}
```

Then only code with `using FooCorp.MagicApp` will see your class (this is a good thing for retaining sanity; there are *lots* of classes in the .NET framework)

Comment: thank you very much marc, that makes complete sense, i'm trying it out now. i wish i could buy knowledge lol

Comment: You can - they're called books ;-)

Comment: Why buy when there are 100s of tutorials out there for free!

Comment: omg i like SOOO didnt know that! lol ;) +1 for sense of humor

Comment: @Marc +1 for deciphering the question
@baeltazor if it's the right answer accept it?

Answer (score 4):

```
public class Foo
{
   public static Foo Create()
   {
     //do stuff
   }

   public void Save()
   {
     //do stuff
   }
}
```

You call them differently, because of the static keyword

```
Foo f = Foo.Create();
f.Save();
```

and I recommend this book - http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596003760

Note that create is really not the best static method in the world because of things called constructors, but for the sake of examples...

Answer (score 1):

If you're confused to how classes and objects work, try to read a book (as [Russell Steen points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666969/creating-a-class-in-c/1666999#1666999)).

The terminology in tutorials and programming books may confuse beginners, if this is the case for you then try to fetch a programmer who does know and watch him code a class while asking as many questions you can until you *get it*. Programmers are generally a nice bunch of people.

If you really want to learn more about OOP (Object Oriented Programming), watch someone do some [code kata](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001138.html) or TDD.

Good luck writing your classes!

Comment: thank you for the advice Spoike :D i wish i knew a programmer i could watch

Comment: yeah, those pesky programmers are usually hiding somewhere in some basement or something. but once you do find someone, they should be fairly helpful.